# How to upload php appllication to remote LAMP server

Tags: php, lamp, digital-ocean

I'm new at php. I just installed lamp to my ubuntu server. Ubuntu server is on the digitalocean. I can connect server with ssh and i can write some easy things to /var/www/html .Is there any easy way to upload whole php application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect via FTP if this service is installed on your machine.

For example you can use [FileZilla](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjar9mvlN_LAhXGaxQKHXE8B4QQFgggMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffilezilla-project.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNGk29GabeehesFbZH8JF3yxkKf73A) as FTP Client, login with given username and password, select the php project and upload to server.

If Digital Ocean provided you a Management Panel like cPanel/Parallels/.. you can log in that and upload via a builtin file manager.